# How to convert tracking value "X" to kerning equivalent in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a photoshop tracking value of 50.How to i convert it to equivalent kerning value in objective-c/swift.I know about attributed text.I just want to know how to get iOS app applicable kerning from photoshop tracking value.

I am currently using `characterSpacing = fontSize * tracking / 1000` which i got from this [link](http://www.devsign.co/notes/tracking-and-character-spacing)

Comment: And what's wrong, what do you expect? Kerning is too big? Too small?

Comment: Its small for 50 kerning at 24 font size